# UIEdgeInsets on UIBarButtonItem for iOS10 causes images to squash

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Hey I have a navigation bar like so:

[image]

To fine tune the placement of the `UIBarButtonItem`s on the right side I need to use image insets. I have a convenience init method for initializing the buttons:

```
convenience init(type: ButtonType, target: Any?, selector: Selector) {
  let image: UIImage = type.image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
  self.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
  imageInsets = type.imageInsets
}
```

This works well but for iOS10 the buttons look like so:

[image]

Why does this happen? What can I do to fix it?

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you used only right inset.

You can try: right inset = 10, and left inset = -10.